# How to check a Wordpress plugin is activated in a Codeception acceptance test

Tags: php, wordpress, codeception

I am learning how to write a plugin in Wordpress and I want to test how the plugin behaves when it is activated. I am using [Codeception/Wp-Browser](https://codeception.com/for/wordpress) as TDD framework. I intend to write an **acceptance test** using the module WpWebDriver with Chrome.

The problem is that the tests I have written interfere with each other. For that reason, I need to reset the state of the plugin before each test, but I don't know how to do it.

Before each test I need to:

- test if the plugin is active
- if it is, then deactivate it
- if it is not, then do nothing

I know I can use the `_before` method inside a Cest class. Here is my code:

```
<?php
class activationCest
{
    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {        
        // what to do here???
    }

    public function _after(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function activationCaseFailPHP(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('see an error message if the PHP version 
                    is not compatible with the plugin');

        $I->loginAsAdmin();
        $I->amOnPluginsPage();
        $I->activatePlugin('testwidget');

        $I->see('Your PHP version is outdated. 
                 Testwidget requires a PHP version equal or superior
                 to 7.0. Contact your hosting provider about 
                 how to update PHP');
    }

    public function activationCaseFailWP(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('see an error message if the Wordpress version
                    is not compatible with the plugin');

        $I->loginAsAdmin();
        $I->amOnPluginsPage();
        $I->activatePlugin('testwidget');

        $I->see('Your Wordpress version is outdated. 
                 Testwidget requires a Wordpress version equal 
                 or superior to 5.0. Contact your hosting provider
                 about how to update Wordpress');
    }

    public function activationCaseSuccess(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo('see a success message if the PHP and Wordpress versions are 
                    compatible with the plugin');

        $I->loginAsAdmin();
        $I->amOnPluginsPage();
        $I->activatePlugin('testwidget');

        $I->see('Selected plugins activated', '#message');
    }
}
```

Naïvely, I tried this

```php
public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {        
       if (is_plugin_active('testwidget')) {
          $I->deactivatePlugin('testwidget');
       }
    }
```

Of course, it didn't work. The program threw the error: `[Error] Call to undefined function is_plugin_active()`, because the Wordpress function [is_plugin_active](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/) is not in scope.

The documentation of Codeception says there are [conditional assertions](https://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#Conditional-Assertions) --that is, methods like `canSeeElement` or `cantSeeElement`, used to test that an element is on the page and will not stop the test if they fail. It seems there is something similar for Codeception actions, as you can see [here](https://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#Step-Decorators).

I don't know if these step decorators can be a solution, because I don't understand clearly how they work and how I can set them up.

What do you think is the simplest solution to this matter? How would you solve it if you were in my shoes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceptance tests can't execute any server-side code, so wordpress functions are not available to you, you can only use helper methods provided by WpWebDriver module to interact with website.

Since `see` methods throw exceptions when they can't see what's expected, you can catch that exception and execute another code only if assertion is not satisfied.

```
public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->loginAsAdmin();
    $I->amOnPluginsPage();
    try {
        //it throws PHPUnit Assertion Failed exception if plugin is active.
        $I->seePluginDeactivated('my-plugin');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $I->deactivatePlugin('hello-dolly');
    }
}
```

If you want to reuse this code in many tests files, make it a helper method as documented at https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Helpers